# Laravel count the IP adressess from this month

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, date, laravel-4

I have a visitor counter that works. Now, I need to get the results back to display them into a chart. What I have now in my controller to display them works, but the date is wrong.

This is what I have:

```
$select_stats = DB::table('visitor')->where('visit_date', '>', '2015-04-01')->where('visit_date', '<', '2015-04-30')->get();

        foreach($select_stats as $statics) {

       //change our object to an array
       $statics = array();
}


    return View::make('admin.home.index')->with('stats', $select_stats);
```

I need to get the 'stats' from the current month, so in this case month 4, but if it is may, then it needs to select automatically the stats from the 5th month.

So that is already a problem for me.

Now, I need to loop them in my blade themplate, that works... But the date is in the format

> YYY-MM-DD

I don't want it displaying like that I do prefer the format:

> DD/MM/YYYY

Okay, so far, so good.

I also need to count the IP's that are stored in the database. Also from THAT month.

And also need to loop and display the count.

The database model I have:

[image: Database table]

The table name is called `visitor`.

My blade template for the chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var visitors = [
@foreach($stats as $stat)
                ['{{ $stat->date }}', 500],
@endforeach
            ];
</script>
```

Yes, this works in the script.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're always dealing with the current month, try this:

   `$select_stats = DB::table('visitor')->whereBetween('visit_date', array(date('Y-m-01'), date('Y-m-t')))->get();`

the lowercase *t* in the date function returns the number of days in the given month (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

2. Simply put, to convert that date format in your template, you could echo it as the following:

   `{{ date('Y/m/d', strtotime($stat->date)) }};`
3. To get the count of the IP's you could perform the same query but add replace `->get()` with `->count()` like so:

   `DB::table('visitor')->whereBetween('visit_date', array(date('Y-m-01'), date('Y-m-t')))->count();`
4. You already have the IP field from the first query, so just echo out `{{$stat->ip}}`

There's always different & better ways to achieve certain results, but without context, here's a solution that works.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but how can I count the amount of IP's during that specific day? so the stats are correctly linked? because I want to display in total a month, but all days.

Comment: Now I have this view: http://prntscr.com/6v5e4u ad this controller: http://prntscr.com/6v5e72